# invoke set method in constructor with scanner

Tags: java, input, constructor, method-call

I am trying to invoke a set method in a constructor that accepts user input to instantiate an object.  A sample of a set method is as follows:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    if(name.length()>0 && name.length()<25) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    else {System.out.println("Name length can not exceed 25 characters.");}
}
```

I then want to accept the user input to instantiate the object.  I currently have it formatted like so:

```
public Character(String name){ name = setName(input.nextLine());}
```

I have imported the scanner and created a scanner object.  The character constructor itself is actually quite large, it consists of 29 variables, each of which have a set method similar to the first code sample.

My ultimate goal is to put this in a GUI form for a person to fill out.  The error Eclipse gives for my current syntax is "type mismatch, cannot convert from void to String".

How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: The issue is here: `name = setName` because `setName` is a `void` method it does not return anything. Why would you need `setName` to return the `name` anyway? A setter does exactly that - it sets the variable. You're basically mixing a setter with a getter here and it's unclear why.

Comment: Look at `public void setName(String name) {` - what is this telling about what the method will return?

Comment: Your constructor accepts a `name` argument and _also_ accepts a name as input???  That paradox aside, accepting input in a constructor is never a good idea.

Comment: And don't use names that are part of the standard Java, such as Character!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach is to modify your code like this:

```
public String setName(String name) {
    if(name.length()>0 && name.length()<25) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    else {System.out.println("Name length can not exceed 25 characters.");}
    return name;
}
```

Comment: What is the point in having a setter method return the field it just set? I don't think this is a good approach, rather you should guide the OP to use a setter properly.